# In Kali Linux, why do I only see python2 and python3 binaries (NOT a 'python' binary) in /usr/bin/ and get "python command not found"

Tags: python, linux, python-2.x, pyenv, kali-linux

I am running latest version of Kali Linux:

```
uname -a                           
Linux User 5.14.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.14.16-1kali1 (2021-11-05) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It already came with Python 3.9.8. But I needed to install Python 2.7. So I first installed it with `sudo apt install python2.7.18.` But following happened:

```
python -V        
Command 'python' not found, did you mean:
  command 'python3' from deb python3
  command 'python' from deb python-is-python3

python2 -V  
Python 2.7.18

python3 -V       
Python 3.9.8
```

Also:

```
which python
python not found
```

***WHAT I TRIED:***

I checked locations such as `/usr/opt/`, `/usr/bin/`, `/usr/share/` etc. I checked `/usr/bin` and found python2 and python3 binaries:

[image]

So I reckoned that python environment variable is not set. I added `python=/usr/bin/python2`  to `/etc/environment` and then did `source /etc/environment`. **But that did not help.**

Then I checked `/usr/share` and found that `python` folder Was there.

[image]

---

Then I did some research on the internet and found [`pyenv`](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/using-eol-python-versions/), which apparently allows us to install and use multiple Python versions without them conflicting with each other. So I followed all steps in the given guide to isntall Python 2.7.18 and set it as default. **But that did not solve the problem either**

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python3-openssl git

curl https://pyenv.run | bash

echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.zshrc     

echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.zshrc

exec $SHELL

pyenv 2.2.3

pyenv install 2.7.18

pyenv global 2.7.18
```

Then I checked:

```
pyenv versions                                                                                                                                                                              1 ⨯
  system
* 2.7.18 (set by /home/bruno/.pyenv/version)
```

**So far so good. But then:**

```
python           
Command 'python' not found, did you mean:
  command 'python3' from deb python3
  command 'python' from deb python-is-python3
```

Moreover, to confirm:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Because that distribution wants to be clear about which version of Python you're running, and [it's perfectly allowed to do so](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/).

In short, you'll have to use `python3` to run Python 3.x, and `python2` (if such a symlink gets set up by `pyenv`, or if you `apt install python2.7` (if it's even available on Kali)) to run Python 2.x.

Please remember Python 2.x is EOL, and you shouldn't use it for any new development.

Comment: And if you want to have python3 as the default, you can symlink it yourself `sudo ln -s $(which python3) /usr/bin/python`

Comment: @sshow Or, preferably, `apt install python-is-python3` so the distribution takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Manually adding path to `/home/bruno/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/bin` to $PATH environment variable solved the `python command not found` for me, because that directory contains `python` binary.

Comment: You're just inviting trouble doing that, if you ask me. Why do you need `python` to be Python 2 in the first place?

Comment: Because somebody handed over some scripts to me which require python2 and refer to it as python. I just need to connect to vpn using openvpn and use obfsproxy because government has banned vpn. My colleague gave me config files and scripts and did set up in Windows infront of me, and said, "You'll need Python 2 and also virtual env". I am just trying to copy their steps and get my obfsproxy and vpn up and running

Comment: It would be better and more future-proof to just change those scripts to use `python2` instead of `python`.